# Apache POI dont write some values in xls - Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls

I'm trying to write in a xls file some values using Apache POI. 
these values are recieved from the object Dados, that is a list with a lot of values.
there are three types of values: *Dipole Moment*, *Alpha Occ Eigen Values* and *Alpha Virt Eigen Values*

in this case, the values are:

DPM: 3.4593

AOEV: -0.23071

AVEV: -0.03402

but, in the table, it only writes the AVEV, like in this image:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNqsr.png)
and yes, The program finds those values
the code is:

```
          String arquivo = IO.getFolder() + "/resultado.xls"; // caminho
          System.out.println("Caminho: " + arquivo);
          HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
          HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Resultados");

          int coluna = 0;
          Row cbc = sheet.createRow(0);
          Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
          int i = 0, auxx = 1;

          for (Dados d : dados) {
                 // Row - linha / Column - Coluna
                 if (i == 0) {
                        cbc.createCell(1+i).setCellValue("Arquivo - "+d.getNome());
                        // Dipole Moment Total
                        row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Dipole Moment");
                        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(d.getDipoleTotal());
                        System.out.println("DPM: "+d.getDipoleTotal());
                        auxx++;
                        row = sheet.createRow(auxx);
                        // Alpha Occ EigenValues
                        row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Alpha Occ Eigen Values");
                        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(d.getOCCEV());
                        System.out.println("AOEV: "+d.getOCCEV());
                        auxx++;
                        row = sheet.createRow(auxx);
                        // Alpha Virt Eigen Values
                        row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Alpha Virt Eigen Values");
                        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(d.getViert());
                        System.out.println("AVEV: "+d.getViert());
                        auxx++;
                        row = sheet.createRow(auxx);
                        i++;
                 } else {
                        cbc.createCell(1+i).setCellValue("Arquivo - "+d.getNome());
                        // Dipole Moment Total
                        row.createCell(1+i).setCellValue(d.getDipoleTotal());
                        System.out.println("DPM: "+d.getDipoleTotal());
                        auxx++;
                        row = sheet.createRow(auxx);
                        // Alpha Occ EigenValues
                        row.createCell(1+i).setCellValue(d.getOCCEV());
                        System.out.println("AOEV: "+d.getOCCEV());
                        auxx++;
                        row = sheet.createRow(auxx);
                        // Alpha Virt Eigen Values
                        row.createCell(1+i).setCellValue(d.getViert());
                        System.out.println("AVEV: "+d.getViert());
                        auxx++;
                        row = sheet.createRow(auxx);
                        i++;
                 }
          }
```

I have no clue of why is this happening. if someone knows, please tell me!
thank you!

Comment: Cannot reproducing. Your code does not show the issue. It sets all cell values. Please show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) containing reproducible code which shows the issue.. But the logic of your code is wrong for a `List<Dados> dados` containing multiple  `Dados` objects. Please show how that should look like in `Excel`.